# ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype when "fetch next 1 rows only" is used

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00997

We have a table called CONTACT_INFO that has a column COMMENTS of type LONG.

These queries work fine:

```
select comments from contact_info;
select comments from contact_info where rownum <= 3;
```

However, this query throws ORA-00997:

```
select comments from contact_info fetch next 3 rows only;
```

Why?

Comment: Avoid the use of the arcane `LONG` type. You are asking for trouble. Use CLOB or BLOB instead. The Oracle metadata uses it sometimes and it's just a pain in the neck to retrieve anything stored in it, or comparing it to other things.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this error in dbFiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=509091be3c92ab15d6238b5b37307fd8

Comment: Please see this post for updating your datatypes https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_long_lob.htm